# What is the difference between these two approaches to a generic method to serialize an object?

Tags: c#, class, generics, json.net

Creating a helper method to output any object as a JSON string. Both these approaches have the same result, but what makes them different? And which would be more suitable in different scenarios? If any?

**Method 1:**

```
public static void OutputAsJson<T>(T o)
{
    EventHandling.Logging.CreateTextEvent($"{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o)}");
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
public static void OutputAsJson(object o)
{
    EventHandling.Logging.CreateTextEvent($"{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o)}");
}
```

Comment: They aren't even different approaches. They're literally calling the exact same method. The parameter passed to `SerializeObject` is `object`. In the first example you're casting `T` as `object`. In the second example `o` has already been cast as `object`. But in both cases you're calling exactly the same method.

Comment: Thanks, was just interested in whether there was any difference or benefit of one over the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equivalent (they make the same `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` [call](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm)).

The second is likely *slightly* better since it avoids some of the [costs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generics-in-the-run-time) of the first code sample. *Generics definitely can be useful in many contexts - but using them in this specific context does not have any benefits.*

Comment: Thanks, was just curious :)

Comment: @JamesMatson Next time, consider right-clicking on `SerializeObject` and `Go To Definition` to see what method it calls. If you do that on both, you'll quickly see that they both make the same method call. So the only real difference, as per my second line, is the cost of using generics.